# Ruby On Rails: therubyracer x86-mingw32 missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I tried to start Server with command `rails -s` that throw an error:

> Could not find gem 'therubyracer x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed i
>   n your Gemfile.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I also try with

```
gem install 
gem update ...
```

but no effect

my gem file:

```
gem 'therubyracer', group: :production
```

I don't know why that can not run! but run with another project is OK.
how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `bundle install --without production` to skip that gem being installed for development.

Comment: ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["development"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"

Comment: Try using `bundle install --without production`